# Get n documents in a loop from mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of 101 documents, I need to iterate over them taking 10 collections at a time and store a value of a particular field(of 10 documents) in a list.

I tried this:

```
values = db.find({},{"field":1})
urls = []
count = 0
for value in values:
if(count < 10):
    urls.append(value["field"])
    count = count + 1
    print count
else:
    print urls
    urls = []
    urls.append(value["field"])
    count = 1
```

It doesn't fetch the last value because it doesn't reach if condition. Any elegant way to do this and rectify ths situation?

Answer (score 1):

You reset `count` to `0` everytime the loop restarted. Move the declaration outside the loop:

```
count = 0
for value in values:
```

If `urls` is already filled, this will be your only problem.

Comment: Should probably reset in `else` too, or use `% 10`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not sure if i understand the question enough to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you've some data that you want to organize into batches of size 10. If so, perhaps this will help:

```
N = 10

values = list(db.find({},{"field":1}))

url_batches = [
    [v['field'] for v in values[i:i+N]]
    for i in xrange(0, len(values), N)
]
```

Comment: Len(values) should be values.count() since values is a cursor.
Also after rectifying this, throws an error:
in <module>
    for i in xrange(0, count, N)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 504, in __getitem__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 354, in __check_okay_to_chain
pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot set options after executing query

Comment: @wannaC If you've only got 101 documents, you can probably get away with converting from cursor to list (see edit).